# Add cordova to already created html\css\js project

Tags: cordova

I have a Project in **HTML/CSS/JS** etc, I want to make its APK. My current project folder structure contains these things:

projectName

css

js

lib

templates

views

app.js

index.html

So how can I add **Cordova** to my project which is ALREADY CREATED?

Comment: Is this a node project? Just plain HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: backbone and some other libraries are used

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Create a new cordova project.
- Add your files into the /www folder of the project.
- Reference the "cordova.js" file in your index.html page.

PS: Please dont alter or change "cordova.js", "cordova_plugins.js" and "plugins" folder when adding files to your /www folder. (Cordova 3.0 +)

As QuickFix said, "**you don't add cordova to a html5 project but you add your html5 files to a cordova project.**"

Hope it helps.

Comment: What you might want to add to your answer: create a symlink between your project folder and your cordova `/www` folder. A symlink is a link between 2 files or folders, if the content of the first folder alters, the defined target alters as well (it's a copy). This way you can keep your project clean. You can create a symlink like this: `ln -s ~/project-folder/dist ~/cordova/www`. Linux example and the path names are examples. The second path is the target.

Comment: Make sure you deleted the `www` before creating the symlink, though. Otherwise you will create a `dist` duplicate _inside_ the `www` folder. You don't want that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have created this folders and files manually, I suggest you to create another new project with Cordova command line, then move your files to the newly created project.

`cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

Comment: so i can't add directly to my project

Comment: html5 www folder is a part of a cordova project, not the opposite. So you don't add cordova to a html5 project but you add your html5 files to a cordova project. If you want to use phonegap build, then you can just add a config.xml to your project and then update everything to phonegap build.

Comment: And instead of creating a cordova project with default www folder and then replace this folder with your sources like described in this answer, I'd suggest to instead add parameter to use existing sources when creating project.

Comment: thank You, more descriptive answer above but also u nice thats why +